# What form does xarr and yarr have to be in in order to return all the co-ordinates that satisfy the equation

Tags: matlab, function, find

I'm currently looking to get this bit of code working in MatLab. I just wondering what form xarr and yarr have to be in for this to return values corresponding to coordinates of points within a circle.

`cir1=find((xarr-cirx1).^2 + (yarr-ciry1).^2 <=cirr1^2);`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: exist. This code will give you if a point is in a circle (without the `find`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xarr` and `yarr` can be scalars, vectors or matrices of any dimensions or sizes, BUT they must be of same sizes. So `cir1` will contain indices of elements in `xarr` and `yarr` that their corresponding 2d point lie inside the circle.

```
%% generating a grid of points
x = (-1:0.02:1)*2*cirr1+cirx1;
y = (-1:0.01:1)*2*cirr1+ciry1;
[xarr, yarr] = meshgrid(x, y);
% xarr and yarr are both 101 by 101
cir1=find((xarr-cirx1).^2 + (yarr-ciry1).^2 <=cirr1^2);

%% generating a list of random points 
points = bsxfun(@plus, (rand(1000, 2)-0.5)*2*cirr1, [cirx1, ciry1]);
xarr = points(:, 1);
yarr = points(:, 2);
% xarr and yarr are both 1000 by 1
cir1=find((xarr-cirx1).^2 + (yarr-ciry1).^2 <=cirr1^2);
```

[image]